# AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda - handling client certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am looking to build an API orchestration layer using API Gateway and Lambda.

For my basic use case I want to have a Python script in Lambda that will just relay the request received at the API Gateway from the client (mobile app in this case) and call an external HTTPS service as the backend.

My question is:
Our mobile client uses client certificates to talk to our HTTPS endpoint today.
How do I go about intercepting that client certificate in my new API Gateway + Lambda setup?

Answer (score 3):

Responded [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=241148&tstart=0). Copying the answer below for StackOverflow audience-

===

Unfortunately, API Gateway does not support client certificate validation from clients to API Gateway at the moment. We do, however, support [client side SSL certificates for authentication by the backends](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

Depending on your use-case, you can use various other options in API Gateway to authenticate/authorize your calls from the mobile client; eg API Keys, Custom Authorizers etc. The request from API Gateway to Lambda should already be encrypted.

Hope that helps,
Ritisha.

Comment: Given almost a year has past, is there any update here?  I am looking to secure my API (exposed via API Gateway/Lambda) with client certificates.

Comment: this would be a really nice feature. I'd like to see it added soon.

Comment: Same question - Is the comment API Gateway does not support client certificate validation from clients to API Gateway still true?   I would like the ability to use a certificate from an external CA.